# PHP function return true or false

Tags: php, if-statement, return-value

I am trying to create a function that will check against the data from the database. If the results are empty, continue with the code. If else, abort.

Here is an example of my code.

```
function check_if_blocked(){
 global $wpdb;
 $user = '1';
 $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE user = $user");
 if(empty($results)){
   $var = false;
  } else {
   $var = true;
  }
 return $var;
}
```

Function check_if_blocked is going to be used multiple through out the plugin.

Here is an example of how I plan on using check_if_blocked()..

```
function msg_form(){
if(check_if_blocked(){
  echo '<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="msg">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">';
  }
 }
```

Regardless on how I switch around the true, false, and even if(!check_if_blocked...

Comment: Problem #1: `$user` doesn't exist inside the [scope of your function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), consider passing it as an [argument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Comment: Regradless of "Problem #1" The code doesn't work.

Comment: i don't know answer but all this code: `if(empty($results)){
   $var = false;
  } else {
   $var = true;
  }
 return $var;` may be changed to `return !empty($results);`

Comment: Is wpdb from wordpress? I'm asking because the users table in wordpress usually doesn't have a column called "user". I doubt that's the cause but it might be worth checking.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return the wrong value, get_results will return true if the query was successful, not if it found matches, so, it might return true even if there are no matching records found, try this instead:

```
function check_if_blocked()
 {
  global $wpdb;
  $user = '1';
  $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE user = $user");
  if(!$results) {return false;}  // query failed, no way to know if there are matching records.
  $numrows = count($results); // query worked, now, check if there are matching records.
  if (is_int($numrows) && $numrows) {$var = true;} else {$var = false;}
  return $var; // return the result.
 }
```

Now, the function will return true only if there are one or more matching records.

Also, you have a syntax error here:

```
if(check_if_blocked(){
```

It should be:

```
if(check_if_blocked()){
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given.

Comment: I re-edited my reply to match the database system you are using, try it now.

Answer (score 0):

After everyone's advice. I finally got it to work. Here is my code.

```
function check_if_blocked($blocked){
global $wpdb;
$user = '1';
$user2 = '2';
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE blocked = $user AND blocker = $user2");
if(empty($results)){
$blocked = 'not_blocked';
} else {
$blocked = 'is_blocked';
}
}

function msg_form(){
if(check_if_blocked($blocked) == 'not_blocked){
echo '<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="msg">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"></form>';
}
}
```